# Only the first message is reaching from client to server in socket programming but the further messages sent from client are not reaching the server

Tags: sockets

I have put a while loop in both client and server to send and recieve messages but only first message is reaching the server. There after the messages sent from client are not reaching the server.

```
 server side:

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <netdb.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

    int socks,portno;
    struct sockaddr_in server,client;
    int newsock,n;
    char buffer[5000];
    int cli_len;

    if(argc < 2)
    {
    perror("\ninsufficient inputs");
    exit(1);
    }

    if((socks = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) < 0)
    {

    perror("\nsocket creation error");
    exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nsocket successfully created");
    bzero((char *) &server, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);
    server.sin_port = htons(portno);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if((bind(socks,(struct sockaddr *) &server,sizeof(server))) > 0)
    {                                    //socket binding
    perror("\nsocket binding failed");
    exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nsocket binding successfull");



    if(listen(socks,5) < 0)
    {
    perror("\nerror in listening");
    exit(1);
    }

    printf("\nlisten succesfull");

    while(1)
    {
    cli_len = sizeof client;
    newsock = accept(socks, (struct sockaddr *) &client,&cli_len);
    bzero(buffer,5000);
    if( (n = recv(newsock,buffer,5000,0)) < 0) //recieving the message
    {
    perror("\nreading from socket failed");
    exit(1);
    }
    printf("read message:%s",buffer);

    //bzero(buffer,5000);
    //buffer[5000] = "got ur message";
    if(( n = write(newsock,"got ur message",14)) < 0)
    {
    perror("\nwrite failed");
    exit(1);
    }
    }
    return 0;
    }

    Client:
```

on the client side it's asking the next message to be sent but all the messages after first message are not reaching the server.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <netdb.h>


    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct hostent *host;
    char buffer[5000];
    int portno,socky,n;

    if(argc < 3)
    {
    perror("insufficient inputs");  //checking the inputs
    exit(1);
    }

    if((socky = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) < 0)   
    { 
    perror("\nerror in socket creation");       //socket creation
    exit(1);
    }

    printf("\nsocket successfully created");

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    server.sin_port = htons(portno);
    host = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if(host == NULL)
    {
    perror("\nerror in getting host address");
    exit(1);
    }

    memcpy (&server.sin_addr.s_addr, host->h_addr,host->h_length);

    if((connect(socky,&server,sizeof(server)))<0) //connecting to server
    {
    perror("\nerror in connection");
    exit(1);
    }
    while(1)
    {

    bzero(buffer,5000);
    printf("\nenter the message");
    fgets(buffer,5000,stdin);
    printf("u have entered the messge:%s",buffer);
    if((n = write(socky,buffer,strlen(buffer))) < 0)   //writing to socket
    {
    perror("\nerror in writing the message");
    exit(1);
    }

    bzero(buffer,1000);
    if (n = (read(socky,buffer,1000)) < 0) //reading from socket
    {
    perror("\nerror in reading from socket");
    exit(1);
    }

    printf("\nmessage recieved:%s",buffer);
    }
    return 0;
    }
```